# Meaning of /bin/zsh -ls % before the command to run in crontab entry

Tags: shell, cron, zsh

I was looking at a crontab file and found the following entry:

`30 05 * * * /bin/zsh -ls % MyScript.sh myConfigFile.ini`

This entry obviously executes `MyScript.sh` with `myConfigFile.ini` as an argument in `zsh`, but what is the meaning of `-ls %` here.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, although it indeed executes `MyScript.sh myConfigFile.ini`, it is not as obvious as it looks.

`-ls` is a shorthand for `-l -s`. These parameters enable certain options in *zsh*

- `-l` enables the option `LOGIN`, which tells *zsh* that it is to be a login shell. This also means that `~/.zprofile` end `/etc/zprofile` (or `/etc/zsh/zprofile` on some systems) are read on initialization and `~/.zlogout` and `/etc/zlogout` on exiting.
- `-s` enables the option `SHIN_STDIN`. This tells *zsh* to read commands from *STDIN*, which is also the default, if no command is specified with `-c COMMAND` and no script is specified. Setting `-s` explicitly also disables taking scripts from the command line. Any arguments that are usually taken as files are taken as normal positional parameters instead (That is, inside the started shell session they will be available in the arrays `$@` and `$*` as well as in the scalar parameters `$1`, `$2`).

So normally `zsh -ls % MyScript.sh myConfigFile.ini` would start a *zsh* login shell with the parameters `$1`, `$2` and `$3` set to `%`, `MyScript.sh` and `myConfigFile.ini`, respectively. It would **not** run `MyScript.sh` and would wait for input from *STDIN* instead.

**But** this is inside a crontab. Here `%` inside a command has a special meaning unless escaped with `\`. Everything after the first `%` will be sent as standard input to the command. Any further `%` will be replaced by newline characters.

So in combination, when `cron` (or its stand-in) runs this crontab entry

```
30 05 * * * /bin/zsh -ls % MyScript.sh myConfigFile.ini
```

it starts `zsh` as a login shell, which will await input on *STDIN*. `cron` then sends `MyScript.sh myConfigFile.ini` as *STDIN* to the shell.

---

Why it was done this way (instead of just `MyScript.sh myConfigFile.ini` or maybe `/path/to/MyScript.sh myConfigFile.ini`) is hard to tell without further information. It may pay to keep in mind that `MyScript.sh` does not have to be a *zsh* script buy may really be anything executable. So it is possible that `MyScript.sh` requires the environment set up in `~/.zprofile`.